# How can I connect my databse by using LINQtoSPARQL for writing linq based services?

Tags: sparql, graphdb, dotnetrdf

The following is the code of `TestDataProvider` class in `LINQtoSPARQL` ([githublinkk](https://github.com/Efimster/LINQtoSPARQL)). Here, data is taken from string or file.

```
namespace LINQtoSPARQLSpace.Tests
{
public static class TestDataProvider
{
    public static ISPARQLQueryable<T> GetQuerable<T>(string data, 
        bool autoquotation = true, 
        bool treatUri = true,
        IEnumerable<Prefix> prefixes = null,
        bool skipTriplesWithEmptyObject = false,
        bool mindAsterisk = false,
        bool useStore = false,
        string defaultGraphUri = "http://test.org/defaultgraph")
    {
        DynamicSPARQLSpace.dotNetRDF.Connector connector = null;

        if (useStore)
        {
            var store = new VDS.RDF.TripleStore();
            store.LoadFromString(data);
            connector = new Connector(new InMemoryDataset(store, new Uri(defaultGraphUri)));

        }
        else
        {
            var graph = new VDS.RDF.Graph();
            graph.LoadFromFile(data);
            connector = new Connector(new InMemoryDataset(graph));
        }


        dynamic dyno = DynamicSPARQL.CreateDyno(connector.GetQueryingFunction(), 
            updateFunc: connector.GetUpdateFunction(),
            autoquotation: autoquotation,
            treatUri: treatUri,
            prefixes:prefixes,
            skipTriplesWithEmptyObject:skipTriplesWithEmptyObject,
            mindAsterisk:mindAsterisk);

        return new SPARQLQuery<T>(dyno);
    }
}
}
```

Now, I want to connect my database (GraphDB ontotext). for now, I am able to connect my database with the help of following lines:

```
Options.ForceHttpBasicAuth = true;
var store2 = new VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri("http://localhost:7200/repositories/786"));      
store2.SetCredentials("admin", "admin");
```

Now, how can I pass this `SparqlRemoteEndpoint` object to `Connector` class object? am I going in the right way to connect?

Please Help.

Comment: you need something that implements `ISparqlDataset` for the `Connector`

Comment: is there anyone who connected their database with above code/